# Is there a definitive documented answer on double quoted string escaping?

Tags: .htaccess, syntax, apache-config

Say, for example, I want to write this header line in an HTTP response:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="I can't believe it's not header!.jpg"
```

It contains a mix of quotes, repeating the quotes doesn't work (despite being the cleanest approach):

```
Header set always Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=""I can't believe it's not header!.jpg"""
```

It throws an error `Header has too many arguments`.

Good old backslash works:

```
Header always set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=\"I can't believe it's not header!.jpg\""
```

but the docs provide [examples where backslashes are used unescaped](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples), so I assume that `"a\b"` is parsed the same as `"a\\b"` because `\b` isn't special like `\` and `"`. We know what they say about assumptions. Am I just being dense? Where are the docs?

---

**Update:** I opened [a bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66372) as I found other oddities.

Comment: Short on time so I can't provide a proper answer — but the parsing source code is [here in server/util.c](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/1c2e67676dd5e64dbe725473ac9fae3f971e0004/server/util.c#L846): `ap_getword_conf` and `substring_conf` together do the work of processing quotes (which can be _either `'` or `"`_) and the only valid escapes are backslash and the _same_ quote character (so `"this is 'legal' without escaping"` and `'this is "legal" as well!'`). All other backslashes will be treated as just literal backslash characters in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash-escapes are certainly the standard way of escaping characters in Apache config files, so backslash-escaping double quotes inside a string that is itself delimited by double quotes is certainly the way to go.

However, *where is this documented*? The page in the Apache docs that covers [configuration file syntax](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html#syntax) does not explicitly cover this. (The only mention of backslashes are in regards to continuing directives across multiple lines - something which is rarely required.)

The [Apache docs for mod_log_config](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html) (a *base* module) do state:

> Literal quotes and backslashes should be escaped with backslashes.

This is where the argument is (always) enclosed in double quotes. The same happens to apply to pretty much all string arguments in all modules.

> but the docs provide examples where backslashes are used unescaped, so I assume that `"a\b"` is parsed the same as `"a\\b"` because `\b` isn't special like `\` and `"`.

I can't see where you are referring to? The link you provide does not seem to include such an example?

If the argument is an *ordinary* string then `"a\b"` would be seen as "ab" (the literal `b` is unnecessarily escaped). And `"a\\b"` would be "a\b" (the backslash itself is escaped for a literal backslash). However, if the argument takes a regex (as many of those [examples on the Apache *expressions* page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples) do) then `\b` itself is a special meta-character that asserts a word-boundary - there is no backslash-escape in this instance.

Note that arguments in Apache config files only need to be surrounded in double quotes if the value contains *spaces*. Many examples in the Apache docs include double quotes, but this is not a requirement. Spaces themselves can often be backslash-escaped (to avoid having to double quote the argument), but this tends to be less readable. For regex arguments it is often preferable use `\s` instead (any *space* character).

Comment: The `"a\b"` was about those examples containing string literals like this: `"expr=%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/special_path\.php$#`. It implies backslashes make it through, otherwise it would not escape the `.` in the regex, therefore `"a\b"`, generally should not be stripped into `ab`. I was not referring to the word-boundary sequence and you could substitute my example characters with `"x\y"`. Thanks for your answer anyway, at least I'm not the only one who could not find explicit docs.

Comment: @Walf Those are not string literals, they are Apache _expressions_ (ap_expr). The double quotes simply surround the ap_expr.  In Apache config files double quotes simply surround the argument, they are not literal string delimiters. Surrounding an argument with double quotes does not change its _type_.

Comment: @Walf An example of an _ordinary string_ argument would be the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ string (2nd argument to the `RewriteRule` directive). eg. `RewriteRule "xy" "a\b"` - the double quotes surrounding the arguments are entirely optional here. The first argument is a _regex_, the second is a _string_ (that supports additional escapes and substitutions). This would result in the request being rewritten to `ab` (the literal `b` was backslash-escaped, which makes no difference here).

Comment: Are you sure they're not string literals *of* expressions? My understanding is that the quotes are simply to delimit the expression parameter because they contains spaces (and may also contain delimiters and delimiter escape characters), but surely the parser reads the quoted string, then passes its *contents* on to the expression parser, as would any language that can contain interpretable code within a string literal.